# Reusing (or linking to) a powerpoint slide, with automatic updates from master

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint

I am building a deck in which I need to use the same slide in several places.
**Not** as a divider with different highlights each time - the slides need to be exactly identical.

- Is there a way to "link" one slide (say slide 18) to a master slide (say, slide 5) so that 18 is always updated to look exactly like 5 ?
- I would also need to do this with a slide on a separate deck

I've tried :

- Duplicating the original slide (copy & Paste): the downside is I need to apply changes to both slides every time I make them, or re-copy.
- Using slide zooms and fitting them to the slide: Issue here is that it is very manual and imprecise. Zooms are hard to perfectly center, which makes slide elements like titles and footnotes misaligned with neighbouring slides.

Is there a built-in PPT feature that allows you to do this ? (or Efficient Elements/ThinkCell functions)

Many thanks,